# Angular optimization with view encapsulation

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I have seen different types of view encapsulations in angular :

1. None
2. Emulated
3. Native (Deprecated) - now Shadow Dom

Question: Does the use of `ViewEncapsulation.None` really reduce the angular build size?

Secondly, If it does reduce the size then should we go for `ViewEncapsulation.None` or we should go for `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` as it prevents the overflow of style rules?

Comment: I think that all the benefits you will loose are far more valuable than a few bites if anything can be improved at all by setting `ViewEncapsulation.None`. What's your primary motivation for doing that?

Comment: There is no difference in bundle sizes at all between encapsulation modes. The reason the sizes would be different is because your CSS must be done differently. Most people can't write good CSS to begin with.